# Trouble in iterating an object to set state

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-hooks

what i'm trying to do here is

- take the input and store it in the city state
- iterate through an object named citylist and set the selectedCity to the city if it exists in citylist else return not found

```
import { createContext, useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { cityList } from '../data/sample-data.js'
import axios from 'axios'

const WeatherContext = createContext()

export const WeatherContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [city, setCity] = useState('')
    const [selected, setSelectedCity] = useState()

    useEffect(() => {
        const timer = setTimeout(() => {
            setCity(city)
            setSelectedCity(() => {
                cityList.cities.filter((siti) => (siti.name === city ? siti : 'notfound'))
            })
            // console.log(selected)
        }, 500)

        return () => {
            clearTimeout(timer)
        }
    }, [city])

    // async function fetchData(url) {
    //  const response = await axios.get(url)
    //  console.log(response)
    // }

    return (
        <WeatherContext.Provider
            value={{
                city,
                setCity,
                cityList,
                // fetchData
            }}>
            {children}
        </WeatherContext.Provider>
    )
}

export default WeatherContext
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to call `setCity(city)` inside the `useEffect`, because you are already setting the `city` state when you take the input. Calling `setCity` with the same value will trigger an infinite re-render in case that city is reference type variable.

And you are using `filter` to find the selected city, but `filter` returns an array, not a single value. If you want to find the first matching city, you should use `find` instead of `filter`.

For example:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const timer = setTimeout(() => {
    const matchedCity = cityList.cities.find((siti) => siti.name === city);
    setSelectedCity(matchedCity ? matchedCity : "notfound");
  }, 500);

  return () => {
    clearTimeout(timer);
  };
}, [city]);
```

Comment: Thanks brother! As a React beginner i really get confused if i should use vanilla js inside a react app that it doesn't even cross my mind

Comment: You're welcome, bro! I'm glad I could help you. React is a powerful and popular framework, but it also has some quirks and pitfalls that can be confusing for beginners. Don't worry, you will get better with practice and learning from others.

Comment: @Nikhil, If you have any questions, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: In that case can you help me with my project? I'm building a small weather fetching app

Comment: Sure, I can try to help you with your project. What kind of weather fetching app are you building? What language and framework are you using?

Comment: i'm using Just React with axios to make request ,as i couldn't find a free api so i hardcoded a sample data into an object as it is just for a dummy project. The problem i'm facing is my state is updating but my component isn't ,rest is working just fine

Comment: here's the link to my repo https://github.com/Nikhil-13/Weather-App

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do here

```
useEffect(() => {
        const timer = setTimeout(() => {
            setCity(city) // <---
            setSelectedCity(() => {
                cityList.cities.filter((siti) => (siti.name === city ? siti : 'notfound'))
            })
            // console.log(selected)
        }, 500)

        return () => {
            clearTimeout(timer)
        }
    }, [city])  // <---
```

This should be causing infinite loop.

Secondly, your filter function is not properly written. It should be as follows

```
cityList.cities.filter(city1 => city1.name === city)[0] || 'notfound'
```

Remember it is not a map function. You need to return Truthy or Falsy value to indicate whether the element should exist in the filtered array. In your case you are not filtering at all. And you need a single result, but you are setting entire array.

Hope this helps. Please work on the basics

Comment: It should, as soon as you try to update the city, if it's an object